# Node.JS - How to Run Node Command from any path?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I have installed the latest node.js from [here](http://blog.nodejs.org/) . I see the %Path% variables have been set for Node.js. But, When i run node from C:\ , i get a "Node is not an recognized comman". But node command is working fine from "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs" path. Can i not run Node commands from C:\ or Say from an other path if i set the Env variables right? Please help. I am running a Win7 X64.

Thank You,
Faraaz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens if you run `node --version`? I have never tried node.js from windows but if that doesn't work there is something wrong with your paths.

What do you get when you run `echo %PATH%`?

Comment: As i have said, it does not work from C:\ path but works fine from its native path at C:\Program Files(x86)\nodejs

Comment: ECHO output has the "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs" node path

Answer (score 11):

I had the exact same problem, but in my PATH variable I had: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`.
After changing it to `C:\Program Files\nodejs` I could access it from anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You should check if the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs` is present in your `%PATH`. If not, add it via the system properties (persistent change). In any case, restart your command prompt, it'll reload the `%PATH` variable. If you're lucky, it should work now :)

Comment: I can see the node path if i ECHO the %PATH% in command prompt. But still no luck.

Comment: Did you restart the prompt ? Does the path is separated by a semi-colon ; ?

Comment: Yes, It is. Node path is at the last of the list without the ;

Answer (score 3):

Most likely it happens because there is no Node path in your PATH environment variable.

I see two ways to solve this

1. Just add Node path into the end of PATH.
2. Reinstall Node as administrator

run [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) (or some file manager) with administrator privileges >>
browse to node-installer.msi >> open it, install node >> enjoy

Answer (score 2):

My Sublime was working with Nodejs fine. I could press Alt-R and see the output from Node in Sublime. Then at some point I upgraded Sublime. I now have version 2.02 build 2221
And at some later point I tried Alt-R and got this infamous message

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command

But it had worked, so what changed?

The steps I took to fix it were to install git bash and then

```
$ git clone https://github.com/tanepiper/SublimeText-Nodejs.git
$ cd SublimeText-Nodejs/
$ git checkout 095ba03344
```

Back in Sublime I clicked *Preferences > Browse Packages*. This opened up Windows Explorer with the folder:

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages
```

I replaced the contents of the Nodejs folder with the git version. Re-started Sublime and then Alt-R sprang back into life.

Other things that turned out to be irrelevant were changing the file *Nodejs.sublime-settings* and tampering with system environment variables. The only thing that worked was **095ba03344** as described here
https://github.com/tanepiper/SublimeText-Nodejs/pull/39