# How to run node from command prompt?

Tags: node.js

I installed Node version 6.7.0. Then from command prompt if I type "node -v" I get following:
[image]

If I type "node.exe -v" it works fine. Also please note I typed "node" but it interpreted it as "node.js".Is it a problem of file association? How to get rid of it?

Comment: Related or possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059211/error-code-800a1391-source-microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-running-grunt-mod

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278143/node-js-how-to-run-node-command-from-any-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are opening "node.js" file using Windows Script Host (check that ADMIN/node.js file exists at disk). This error isn't NodeJS.
In second case you are really running node.js