# on every node command i am getting error:object expected and displays code:800A138F

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Am new to node js. Trying to install nodejs. I did install and later when i try to run node -v command am getting below error.

```
> object expected 
> code:800A138F. 
> Microsoft JScript runtime error
```

None of the node commands are working. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't double clicked anywhere. After installing node.js and restarting my laptop, i just opened command prompt and typed node -v

Comment: By any chance is your script named `node.js`?

Comment: I havent written any script yet. After installation, trying to just run the command node -v  in command prompt of windows. Doing this does it run any default script?

Comment: Just a wild guess based on what I saw here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858431/how-to-run-node-from-command-prompt . You could try `node.exe -v`, see if there's a difference.